# how can I center a <p> inside of <div>

Tags: html, css

How can I place a `<p>` inside the div? When I use `text-align:center;` it centers from the full width, but I want it at the center from the end of the sidebar. I tried `float: center;` as well but didn't work either.
https://jsfiddle.net/umklapper/4be1pus5/2/
what I want is:

```
           |
sidebar    |<------------------------------center----------------------------------------------->
           |
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

.video {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  /* Same width as the sidebar + left position in px */
  font-size: 28px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
</div>
<div class="video">
  <p>Hey! Welcome to my website!</p>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ObdvMkCKws" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your sidebar has fixed position, so it doesn't affect the positioning of the other content. Try looking into [flex layouts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You should wrap the whole thing, sidebar and content, in a `flex` parent, and then center the content in `.video`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.item {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  display: block;
}

.video {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="menu">
    <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <p>Hey! Welcome to my website!</p>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ObdvMkCKws" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the menu bar is fixed so the content underneath is being centered to the full width of the window.

Here is a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/phrd3q5v/

By wrapping the content in a container and making that container minus the width of the side menu the content can be centered.

```
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

As attributes of your class `video`